# Excluir algunos valores de una consulta

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo un select muy grande con muchos valores y me gustaría saber si en vez de seleccionar los que quiero hay una forma de seleccionar los que no quiero que traiga la consulta.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
  // Filtro de busqueda de las facturas
    $reportes = Factura::cliente_id($request->get('cliente_id'))
    ->tipo_factura($request->get('tipo-factura'))
    ->tiempo($request->get('date_desde'), $request->get('date_hasta'))
    ->select('documento', 'bienes', 'ncf', 'ncf_modificado',' date_comp', 'date_pago',
            'tipo_bien', 'monto_servicios', 'monto_bienes',  'monto_total',  'itebis_fact',
            'itebis_retenido', 'itebis_sujeto', 'itebis_costo', 'itebis_adelantar', 'itebis_compras',
             'tipo_retencion', 'monto_retenido', 'isr', 'impuesto_consumo', 'otros_impuestos',
             'propina', 'forma_pago' )
    ->orderBy('created_at' ,'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Este es el modelo:

```
//Query Scopes
     public function scopeCliente_id($query, $id){

        if($id !=""){
           $query->where('cliente_id', '=', $id);
         }
    }

    public function scopeTipo_factura($query, $tipo){

        if($tipo !=""){
           $query->where('tipo_factura', '=', $tipo);
         }
    }

    public function scopeTiempo($query, $fecha1, $fecha2){

        if( trim($fecha1) != '' and trim($fecha2) != '' ){
            $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$fecha1, $fecha2]);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Ya lo modifique con el modelo. Gracias por aclarar.

Comment: Puedes agregarlos a la propiedad `$hidden` del modelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas Eloquent, el modelo tiene 1 de tantas propiedades que te van a ayudar a obtener el resultado buscado:

Por ejemplo declara una propiedad protegida llamada `$hidden` en la cual el valor pasado es un vector de valores los cuales serán los nombres de las columnas que NO deseas aparezcan en el resultado:

```
protected $hidden = [
    'columna1', 'columna2', 'columnaN'
];
```

Comment: Podría, pero en algunos casos también uso los valores que no quiero mostrar en el filtro. Que haría en ese caso?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un scope para excluir las columnas que no utilizas

```
// Agrega en este array todas las columnas de tu modelo
protected $columns = ['id', 'col1', 'col2'];

// Este scope elimina las columnas que indiques
public function scopeExclude($query, $excluded = []) 
{
    return $query->select(array_diff($this->columns, $excluded));
}

// Al momento de llamar al modelo envia la función con un array de columnas que no quieras mostrar
$reportes = Factura::exclude(['col1']);
```

Comment: Bien ahi, buena forma de volver dinámico el filtro